# Rendering a partial view inside a task

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC controller that runs an email notification function using `Task.Factory.StartNew()` since it pulls a few counts from the database and is not critical enough to hold up the main request. I would like to use some equivalent of [RenderPartialViewToString](https://gist.github.com/cassioeskelsen/831567) to generate the email body, but this throws an error because some web context is not available in the context that the task runs in.

Is there an easy way to accomplish this using the core MVC / Razor libraries, or do I need to resort to something like [RazorEngine](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use RazorEngine.  Here is some code that does something similar

https://bitbucket.org/swaj/actionmailer.net/src/65301af9614b/src/ActionMailer.Net.Standalone/RazorEmailResult.cs?at=default